# could not find method minifyEnabled()

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm working on an Android app using Android Studio. When trying to build the app, I get the following error. But I can't figure out how to fix that. All I did before was removing the /build directories from the SVN repository.

> Error:(16) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
> > Could not find method minifyEnabled() for arguments [false] on BuildTypeDsl_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false,
> >     testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebugBuild=false,
> >     renderscriptDebugBuild=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3,
> >     applicationIdSuffix=null, versionNameSuffix=null, runProguard=false,
> >     zipAlign=true, signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true}.

Here's the part of the gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "...xxx..."
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `minifyEnabled` with `runProguard` or you could update your Gradle version to the newest (recommended). Then minifyEnabled would work. I experienced the very same thing a month ago.

Comment: The current gradle version is: com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2 --> so minifyEnabled should work, right?

Comment: Nope, not according to the docs of Android Studio. It got introduced in 0.14.0 - [Docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I need to figure out how to upgrade gradle. thanks for the hint.

Comment: In the build.gradle for your overall project (as opposed to the one for your app), you should see a line like this `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'` --> put the version of gradle you want in there, then AS should show you "Sync now" at top, click this and it will upgrade your gradle version as required.